# making thread safe calls to controls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

This is quite strange.

I have a background worker doing some work on my Windows Form.
As part of this work a dat grid control is updated.

Once the process is completed, all is well.

If I click the button again to kick off the background worker and start the process again, I get an error `cross thread not valid` on the below code:

```
private void bgProcessing_Production_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] args = (String[])e.Argument;
        e.Result = args[0];

gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;

if (gvTaskCases.Rows.Count != 0) // EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE!
    {
    gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear(); // .Update();
    }
```

Now here's the thing, as I said, it works fine the first time.

But even wierder, if I click *Enable Editing* in the error dialog, then hit **F5** it runs fine.

So have I just been lucky that my code has been running fine for several months, or am I missing something more fundamental?

How should I change this code to avoid a debug error like this?
**UPDATE**:
Here is the full error detail:

```
Reason: System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.LayoutScrollBars()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ComputeLayout()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PerformLayoutPrivate(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows, Boolean invalidInAdjustFillingColumns, Boolean repositionEditingControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.ResetUIState(Boolean useRowShortcut, Boolean computeVisibleRows)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged_PreNotification(CollectionChangeAction cca, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount, DataGridViewRow& dataGridViewRow, Boolean changeIsInsertion)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.OnCollectionChanged(CollectionChangeEventArgs e, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 rowCount, Boolean changeIsDeletion, Boolean changeIsInsertion, Boolean recreateNewRow, Point newCurrentCell)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.ClearInternal(Boolean recreateNewRow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.RefreshColumnsAndRows()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataSource(Object value)
   at SFDetachifier.SFDetachifier.bgProcessing_Production_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\Users\nightcopy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SFDetachifier_2013\SFDetachifier\SFDetachifier.cs:line 1464
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

**EDIT:**
I should mention that I make thread safe calls to other controls such as a textbox using the below code:

```
     private void SetText(string text)
        {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.lblAccessStatus.InvokeRequired)
            {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
        else
            {
            this.lblAccessStatus.Text = text;
            this.lblAccessStatus.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

so do I need to do something similar on the data grid?

Comment: Sounds like Visual Studio is running your code in some sort of "sandboxed mode," where the controls on your Winform are read-only.  It might help if you told us what the exception was.

Comment: You shouldn't try to update UI controls in the operation performed by the background worker. Do any updates in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler since that is run on the UI thread.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I have updated my question with the full error detail, and some more information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lee I do make updates in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler as well, however in this case I need to clear the grid in the `DoWork` in the situation where the process is run again (for example with different date parameters...

Comment: Yes you have been lucky. The WinForms contrrols make the cross-thread check at certain key points but it is possibe to evade those checks. That doesn't mean your code is safe. Use Invoke() for all GUI access.

Comment: THanks Henk, I'm using BeginINvoke in the `DoWork` handler now as proposed by cashinton, and calling `gvTaskCases.dataSource=null` before calling `RunWorkerAsync` on the background worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use InvokeRequired on the control:

```
Action task = () => {
    gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;

    if (gvTaskCases.Rows.Count != 0) // EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE!
    {
        gvTaskCases.Rows.Clear(); // .Update();
    }
};

if(gvTaskCases.InvokeRequired) {
    gvTaskCases.Invoke(task);        
}
else {
    task();
}
```

Comment: @cashinton: I get compile errors when trying your code such as `invalid expression term ")"` and `invalid expression term "("` and `; expected` and `{` expected

Comment: Thanks ever so much, I've taken HAns suggestion too, and called `gvTaskCases.DataSource=null;` before calling `RunWorkerAsync`, then used your code (without that call) in my `DoWork` handler!

Answer (score 4):

```
   gvTaskCases.DataSource = null;
```

You can tell from the call stack that it is *this* statement that causes the crash.  It works the first time because the DataSource property isn't set yet.  So unsetting it cannot have any effect.  But big effect the 2nd time, the grid needs to be updated since it doesn't have any data anymore.  Kaboom when that happens on any thread other than the UI thread.

The DataSource property is **not** threadsafe.

The simple workaround is to set it to null before you call RunWorkerAsync().

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'm setting it to null before I call `RunWorkerAsync` and using cashintons code in the `DoWork` handler.

Comment: It makes no sense to do it both ways.  Invoke() is far too expensive and risky to do nothing at all.  *Always* avoid writing cargo-cult code.

Comment: oh, should I just set it to null then, and miss out the 'rows.clear'?

Comment: I think I should have been doing that cleanup **before** executing the background worker, would have avoided all this as you say!

Comment: I'm gonna remember that `cargo-cult code` for the future when I have 450K points in 10 years time :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem regards to Windows Forms threading model.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8xdz5c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): Windows Forms uses the single-threaded apartment (STA) model because Windows Forms is based on native Win32 windows that are inherently apartment-threaded. The STA model implies that a window can be created on any thread, but it cannot switch threads once created, and all function calls to it must occur on its creation thread. Outside Windows Forms, classes in the .NET Framework use the free threading model.

So you should use Invoke, or you can use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle this kind problem automatically.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is supposed to handle this problem automatically.  Your answer would be a better one if you made that clearer.

Comment: I tried the code suggested by `cashinton` but all I get is compile time errors